# Drupal time based triggers

Tags: drupal-6, triggers, ubercart, action

I'm building an event signup system and integrating it with Ubercart. Each event is a product and has a price and a start time.
I wish to be able to trigger an action one week before the event starts. The action is supposed to send an email to the users that bought the event and perform a capture on the registrant's credit card. But where do I define the action and how do I trigger it one week before event start?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Drupal 6, since you're mentioning ubercart. Does the action to send the email you're takling about already exist?

If it does, you can assign it under Site Building | Triggers | Cron. If it doesn't show up in the list of actions, you might need the [Triggerunlock](http://drupal.org/project/triggerunlock) module.

If the action doesn't exist, you're going to have to write the PHP code to send the emails and do the calculations. You will need to create your own module and either use [hook_cron](http://drupal.org/node/106272), or [create a custom action](http://drupal.org/node/172152).

Comment: Yep. Drupal 6. I have defined my own action in my custom module. But I can't figure out how to write the code that loads the events with the date one week from the day the action runs. Maybe just some custom sql will do. Then I need to find the orders where this event appears. With this I should be able to make a list of the orders and email this list to the admin.